# how to exclude the string and sum number from the text?

Tags: javascript

```
function specialMix(...data) {
    // Your Code Here
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (typeof data[i] === "number") {
            result += data[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

call the function

```
console.log(specialMix(10, 20, 30)); // 60
console.log(specialMix("10Test", "Testing", "20Cool")); // 30
console.log(specialMix("Testing", "10Testing", "40Cool")); // 50
console.log(specialMix("Test", "Cool", "Test")); // All Is Strings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to go here would be a regex replacement:

```js
function specialMix(...data) {
    data = data.map(x => x.replace(/\D+/g, ""));
    return data.reduce((p, a) => a ? p + parseInt(a) : p, 0);
}

console.log(specialMix("10Test", "Testing", "20Cool")); // 30
console.log(specialMix("Testing", "10Testing", "40Cool")); // 50
console.log(specialMix("Test", "Cool", "Test")); // All Is Strings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex will be the shortest way.

There is also a solution that does not use regex, you could use it for reference

Steps:

- exclude non-digit characters in each element
- exclude empty strings
- cast number string to number
- calculate sum

```js
function excludeString(el) {
  return String(el)
    .split("")
    .filter(char => Number.isInteger(+char))
    .join("")
}

function specialMix(...data) {
  return data
    .map(excludeString)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map(Number)
    .reduce((sum, el) => sum + el, 0)
}

console.log(specialMix(10, 20, 30)) // 60
console.log(specialMix("10Test", "Testing", "20Cool")) // 30
console.log(specialMix("Testing", "10Testing", "40Cool")) // 50
console.log(specialMix("Test", "Cool", "Test")) // All Is Strings.
```